# What NLP measures should I use to compare the importance/centrality of certain terms in different documents?

Tags: nltk, data-analysis, nlp

What NLP (natural language processing) measures can I use to measure the importance and centrality of different words in a text or collection of texts?

Example: suppose I have two corpuses containing judicial opinions. Corpus A contains opinions in which the court finds a manufacturer liable for negligently manufacturing a product. Corpus B contains opinions with similar facts but reaching a different result. What measures can be used that would allow me to say that certain terms are more “important” or “central” to the cases in Corpus A than to the cases in Corpus B?

What I’ve tried:
- Raw word frequency 
- [TF-IDF](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/tf-idf-weighting-1.html)

I know there are many more (e.g. from graph theory) but am unsure where to start and have a limited background. I would appreciate any suggestions or explanations of what different measures are used and the pros/cons of each.  FWIW, I’m using NTLK and am also slightly familiar with Spacy.

Background: I am planning an academic law review article that will try to explain why similar cases on a certain topic are decided differently in two different jurisdictions. My hypothesis: different terms are more common in, and central to, each set of cases. For example, cases in set A might use the term “intent” more than similar cases in set B, showing that the first set of cases is more focused on that concept.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question how to **"measure the importance and centrality of different words in a text"**:
The [textacy library](https://textacy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference/information_extraction.html?highlight=keyword#keyterm-extraction) has several algorithms for extracting key terms easily. The current state of the art algorithm for this task seems to be [YAKE](https://github.com/LIAAD/yake) and textacy has an easy to use implementation for it. Note that textacy is built on top of spacy, so it would work something like this:

```
from textacy.ke import yake
import spacy
import wikipedia

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
text = wikipedia.page("Emmanuel Macron").content  # some string to extract key terms from
doc = nlp(text)

keywords = yake(doc, normalize="lemma", include_pos=["NOUN", "PROPN", "ADJ"], window_size=5, topn=10)
```

Regarding **your final goal** to "explain why similar cases [texts] on a certain topic are decided differently in two different jurisdictions":
I'm not sure if keyword extraction is going to help you much for this. If I understand correctly you have two corpora: corpus A with a group of text with known outcome X and corpus B with known outcome Y. You can apply keyword extraction to both corpora separately, but this will just return the words that are most central to the respective corpus. It will not tell you which keywords are most exclusive to corpus A compared to corpus B. (Maybe you can interpret the keywords qualitatively and you might gain some insights qualitatively)

One alternative might be **topic modeling**. A topic model tells you which words are most exclusive to one topic compared to another (a topic is defined as a group of words that often occur together within and across texts). You could combine your two corpora A and B, run topic modeling on the combined corpus and hope that there are certain topics (word combinations) that are correlated with outcome X or Y.
The best library in Python for topic modeling is [Gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/index.html) (but I'm less familiar with it and I have the impression that topic modeling libraries in R are more comprehensive than in Python).